# scala: Type pattern maching

Tags: scala

Another question from the beginner.

I am trying to understand how next piece of code works.
Now sure what is the meaning of the second case statement.

```
   obj match {
        case _: BigInt => Int.MaxValue  
        case BigInt => -1       
    }
```

In first case I will match object against type BingInt
What will be the matching against in the second case?

Comment: case _ : BigInt is a match on the type BigInt and case BigInt is a match on the value BigInt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `case` matches on any value which is a `BigInt`. The second `case` matches on the `BigInt` companion object.

```
def test(obj: Any) = obj match {
  case _: BigInt => Int.MaxValue
  case BigInt => -1
}

scala> test(BigInt(1))
res2: Int = 2147483647

scala> test(BigInt)
res3: Int = -1
```

That said, it's likely that what you really want it's the first case, unless you have any specific reasons to check whether you're passing the `BigInt` companion object to that pattern match.

Comment: Well. Answer is very obvious. Thanks for your help